# Shell navbar with trailing edge text

Tags: c#, .net, shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to put a "trailing edge" text on a Shell navbar like on this pic?

[image]

I'm refactoring a project to use Shell. Before, it was done by changing the toolbar item when the user taps monthly, weekly or daily on that specific page. But now, I'm using Shell with flyout and the tabs are from CommunityToolkit TabView so the "pages" on the tabs are no longer contant pages but content views.
If I add a toolbar it will appear on all views, not only on this specific view.

I would like to add a text at the final of the navbar only on that specific view and change it when the user taps the monthly, weekly or daily options.

This is Xamarin Forms project.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not trigger some code to change the value of the text in a switch case statement that is cased based on your tab selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by ViewModel and TapGestureRecognizer.

ViewModel:

```
namespace Forms_Shell.ViewModels
{
    public class Page1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand TapCommand { get; }
        string selection;
        public string Selection
        {
            get => selection;
            set
            {
                selection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Selection));
            }
        }
        
        public Page1ViewModel()
        {
            Selection = "Monthly";
            TapCommand = new Command<string>(Show);
        }
        private void Show(string a)
        {
            Selection = a;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know the xaml code of the monthly, weekly or daily options, so I use label as an example to replace it. Add a `TapGestureRecognizer` attached to Label:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Forms_Shell.ViewModels" 
             x:Class="Forms_Shell.Views.Page1" 
             Title="Page1">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:Page1ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding Selection}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="50,20">
            <Label x:Name="Monthly" Text="Monthly" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Monthly},Path=Text}" 
                                          Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="Weekly" x:Name="Weekly" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Weekly},Path=Text}" 
                                          Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="Daily" x:Name="Daily" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Daily},Path=Text}" 
                                          Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Update**:

```
<ContentPage 
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Forms_Shell.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Forms_Shell.ViewModels"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit" 
    ...>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:Page1ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding Selection}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="50,20">
            <xct:TabView TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                         TabStripBackgroundColor="Blue" 
                         TabStripHeight="50">
                <xct:TabViewItem Text="Monthly" 
                                 x:Name="Monthly" 
                                 TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow" FontSize="12">
                    <xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Monthly},Path=Text}" 
                                              Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                    </xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>

                    <local:ContentView1/>
                </xct:TabViewItem>
                <xct:TabViewItem Text="Weekly" 
                                 x:Name="Weekly" 
                                 TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow" FontSize="12">
                    <xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Weekly},Path=Text}" 
                                              Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                    </xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>
                    
                    <local:ContentView1/>
                </xct:TabViewItem>
                <xct:TabViewItem Text="Daily" 
                                 x:Name="Daily" 
                                 TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow" FontSize="12">
                    <xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference Daily},Path=Text}" 
                                              Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                    </xct:TabViewItem.GestureRecognizers>

                    <local:ContentView1/>
                </xct:TabViewItem>
            </xct:TabView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell 
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Forms_Shell.Views"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit" 
    Title="Forms_Shell" 
    x:Class="Forms_Shell.AppShell">

    <FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
        <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png">
        <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Page1">
        <ShellContent Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    
</Shell>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jianwei Sun. But I forgot to mention that I'm using CommunityToolkit TabView, so I needed to turn the ContentPages into ContentViews and when I add the ToolBar it appears on all Tabs.

Comment: @HigorPereira I don't understand what you mean. You mean that use TabView in Flyout or Tab of AppShell.xaml? Could you provide some relevant code so that I can reproduce your situation, if it's OK. In addition, I updated the answer. Wish it can meet your need.